# tsharkでデータをcsvに出力する際にタイトル行を追加する方法

Tags: tshark

tsharkを用いて、csv出力しようと下記のように記述をしました。

```
#tshark -r test1.pcap -Y "tcp" -T fields -E separator=',' -e "frame.time_relative"  -e "tcp.window_size"  > Test1.csv
```

csvファイルは正常に出力されます。

```
0.440644000,4096
0.440766000,8181
0.441026000,8192
```

これにタイトル行を追加するには、どうするのが一般的でしょうか。

```
frame.time_relative,tcp.window_size
0.440644000,4096
0.440766000,8181
0.441026000,8192
```

Comment: 簡単には `{ echo 'frame.time_relative,tcp.window_size'; tshark -r test1.pcap ... ; } > Test1.csv` ですかね。`tshark` にヘッダラインを出力するオプションがあるかもしれませんが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-E header=y`をオプションに指定するとヘッダーを追加できます。

```
#tshark -r test1.pcap -Y "tcp" -T fields -E header=y -E separator=',' -e "frame.time_relative"  -e "tcp.window_size"  > Test1.csv
```